# How do Earth 1 and Earth 2 make sense?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Kara describes the planet Earth she found to Lee as green and beautiful and blue, so how could it be the ruined Earth? Or am I remembering incorrectly?

Is there an answer or did the writers mess up? I do not understand how the two Earths fit.

Answer (score 11):

Kara was destined to bring humankind to its end (end of his journey). So, when she tells Lee about the Earth, she was talking about, actually, the Earth 2 (the one that they find at the end of the show). The fact that her visions led the fleet to Earth 1 (the ruined Earth) was merely part of the hard and long journey to the real Earth. The series does not explicitly explain what happened to Kara, but is probable that the Kara that returned from death was not her, but an angel (like Caprica Six and Gaius Baltar) with the mission to lead everyone to Earth.

When they arrive in the Earth 2, Kara realizes that she fulfilled his destiny, and vanishes. This does not happened when they find Earth 1. This is a hint that Earth 2 was the Earth that she saw before.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was about what you understand from the after effects.

Like the Hybrid says, Kara was the harbinger of death. When Kara saw Earth-1, it was aldready destroyed by nukes but I think Kara saw it as the way it looked when it was really green and blue. It was beautiful in her eyes.

When they arrived Earth-1 and saw what happened, she tried to locate the distress signal and found her own body. This makes sense when you remind yourself what the Hybrid said to Kara. She brings the entire human race to their death by dragging them to the destroyed Earth-1.

Kara thinks about that during the evacuation of Earth-1 and they go on. After they revealed what Kara is (Dr. Gaius Baltar reveals it publicly), and lost their hope of salvation they perform their last FTL jump to the Earth-2 by Kara's entered coordinates.

She got those coordiants as a child's sketch from a cylon-human baby (I know how that sounds but you said you watched it :] ), she discovered the sketch was actually the notes of a song, and finally she discovered the numbers (coordinates) behind it.

She brought the human race to Earth-2. It doesn't end here though. In Battlestar Galactica, they repeat a phrase very often.

> "All of this has happened before, and it will all happen again." -
>   Book of Pythia

This is mostly repeated by the cylon named Leoben. But it is the answer to your question.

According to the BSG universe, humans created cylons and they made war over again. If this all happaned before, that means Kara (or some version of her) brought the humans to their death (to a version of Earth-1) multiple times.
This also means she will bring them to their death once more. Which she did. She brought humans and cylons to Earth-2.

It depends on the ending. Will the humans create humanoid robots which will turn against their creator? Will they fight to extinction? Will humans flee? Will the next Kara lead them to Earth-3?